# Ctrl Alt AltGr keys not working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I have a  USB-gaming keyboard (bought on aliexpress sometime ago) with English keys. It works perfectly on Windows, even with the Spanish config.

The problem is that on Linux, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>AltGr</kbd> keys don't work, they are detected all as Left <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys. This is the xev exit:

```
KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x2800001,
    root 0xcd, subw 0x0, time 189078, (97,87), root:(1057,627),
    state 0x10, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x2800001,
    root 0xcd, subw 0x0, time 189150, (97,87), root:(1057,627),
    state 0x11, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x2800001,
    root 0xcd, subw 0x0, time 189294, (97,87), root:(1057,627),
    state 0x10, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x2800001,
    root 0xcd, subw 0x0, time 189366, (97,87), root:(1057,627),
    state 0x11, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x2800001,
    root 0xcd, subw 0x0, time 189990, (97,87), root:(1057,627),
    state 0x10, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

This is the output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0c45:7603 Microdia 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0cf3:9271 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR9271 802.11n
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0e8f:0021 GreenAsia Inc. Multimedia Keyboard Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And this the output of `xinput`:

```
 Virtual core pointer                       id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PixArt USB Optical Mouse                  id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SONiX USB Keyboard                        id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ GASIA USB MSN KB                          id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ SONiX USB Keyboard                        id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Eee PC WMI hotkeys                        id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I use Ubuntutu 16.04, but in older versions the problem is the same. I've tried some fixes and using gnome tweak tool, but that didn't work.

Some ideas?

--Edited:
I just fixed it installing this driver https://bitbucket.org/Swoogan/aziokbd
Working on Ubuntu 18 64 bits.

Comment: I presume the keyboard is connected via USB. Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `lsusb` and `xinput`? Thanks.

Comment: there's a [thread at ubuntuforums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2239909) that references the `Microdia` device seen in your `lsusb` output (apparently the `SONiX` device in the `xinput` output, as opposed to the `GreenAsia` and `GASIA` entries).

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you so much!!